# How to create a stitch Service with query params

Tags: mongodb-stitch

I'm creating a Data API with MongoDB Stitch and i want to know how to create a function with query params (the params must be given when i call my API) i want to give like parametre the collection name when i call my API.

there is my Function

```
exports = function(arg) {
const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
const mycollection = mongodb.db("STM32").collection(arg);
console.log(arg) ;
var array = mycollection.find({}).toArray();  
return array ;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **minimalist example** of such a function:

```js
exports = function(payload, response) {
  // retrieve collection name from querystring (e.g. ?coll=myCollection)
    const {coll} = payload.query;

    // log collection name to confirm receipt from querystring
    console.log("collection name passed: ", coll);

    // query a mongodb service, passing the parameterized collection name
    const doc = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("mydb").collection(coll).find().toArray();

    return  doc;
};
```

**Test in Stitch Function Editor**:

```
exports({query: {coll: 'myCollection'}})
```

**Test outside Stitch** (e.g. in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/))

Use the [Webhook URL](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/reference/service-webhooks/) generated by Stitch, then append the query parameter.

https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/MY_STITCH_APP_ID/service/http/incoming_webhook/MY_WEBHOOK_NAME?coll=myCollection